# htaccess mod_rewrite multiple paths to query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been searching but I can't quite find what I'm after.
I'm trying to find an elegant way to redirect my url path to the query string via htaccess and mod_rewrite.

The problem is that the path does not have a fixed amound of sub dirs and could be huge.

i.e. http://example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/sub5/sub6/sub7...

Currently I just have a load of rules in my htaccess to capture these...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /index.php?sub[]=$1&sub[]=$2&sub[]=$3&sub[]=$4&sub[]=$5 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /index.php?sub[]=$1&sub[]=$2&sub[]=$3&sub[]=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /index.php?sub[]=$1&sub[]=$2&sub[]=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /index.php?sub[]=$1&sub[]=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? /index.php?sub[]=$1 [QSA,L]
```

... but there may be more, anyone know of a way to autoamtically parse these in to the query string?

Comment: This would be a lot easier, if you just passed _any_ path to your script, and then `explode`d that path by `/` within your script …

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this already with something like this but I was wondering if it could all be handled in htaccess

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /index.php?module=$1&cats=$2 [QSA,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the paramater name is always the same, you could just rely on the rewrite engine to loop through them all:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?sub[]=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$2?sub[]=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: sorry but I'm not quite following that, I just get a 404 when trying your example

Comment: @MattJenkins it does exactly what you are asking in your question for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tUxk8.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/tUxk8.png

Comment: ah, ok yeah I've got it now. Thanks!