# How do I configure Apache (.htaccess?) to use mod_rewrite to pass virtual path to PHP file?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a script located at http://www.foo.bar/script and would like to use virtual path names to send data to that script.  For example, http://www.foo.bar/script/this/is/a/path would pass "this/is/a/path" to /script.  I would like to do this without changing the URL the user sees.

I've already gotten this to work with Apache mod_rewrite using something similar to what was suggested here [htaccess mod_rewrite multiple paths to query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699094/htaccess-mod-rewrite-multiple-paths-to-query-string).  What I have not been able to do is to pass the path to the script without changing the URL the users sees.  So, a user that visits http://www.foo.bar/script/stackoverflow/rocks, the script residing at /script would receive /stackoverflow/rocks as a query string or URI but the URL would not change.  I know this is not uncommon, and perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology when searching for an answer.  Thank you for considering.

One idea someone suggested:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "script/(.*)" "https://www.foo.bar/script/?data=$1" [R,L]
```

However, the above changes the URL in the browser.  I don't want to expose "?" on the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have the exact code you need but I have something I use that might just help you. The example above using rewrite_module will rewrite any URL with .php and will also accept the page name without the .php and redirect to a pageName.php witch is close to what you want, the name the users write, redirecting to the script you want. Additionaly it also offer some protection against cross scripting at the end of the URL.

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)(?:%3C|%3E|&lt;|&gt;)(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^((.*)((?!([.]*p*h*p))\w+)) /$1?%1%2 [L,R=302,NE]
</IfModule>
```